# How to make a GUI application run in ubuntu without a desktop manager?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

One of my friends recently asked me if it was possible to run a GUI application in ubuntu without installing a desktop environment. He had a machine at work which functions as their server. Therefore, there isn't any DM or DE installed on it. He wanted to run a browser on it without installing a DE which will clutter things up. While one solution is to install a lightweight desktop environment like xfce or lxde, I decided to figure out a solution which will work without any. I will be posting my solution below because I could not find anything that would work online and I feel that this could help others facing this problem. Feel free to make any suggestions or to suggest  alternative solutions.

*My solution works with Firefox but not with Chrome. The details are down below. If someone figures it out please do leave a comment.

Comment: Have a look at [this video I did](https://youtu.be/6V54DEtgIuw) to show how a minimal custom DE can run with only 160MB of RAM, and even less if you don't run some of the options I have.  I also installed Chrome.  Check my other videos to see how I configured it from scratch.  It's quite easy and very lightweight. I don't even have a DM installed in my video #2, but it's a full functioning DE.

Answer (score 1):

Install xdm and Firefox using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xdm firefox -y
```

Make the a .desktop file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=XSession
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox
TryExec=/usr/bin/firefox
Name=Firefox
Comment=Testing
```

I named mine firefox.desktop but you can name it whatever you want.

Paste this file into /usr/share/xsessions using the following command:

```
sudo mv firefox.desktop /usr/share/xsessions
```

Finally, start xdm using the following command or restart your computer, and choose firefox as your desktop manager.

```
sudo service xdm start
```

In order to quit, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter terminal mode. From here you can shutdown your computer or restart the desktop manager in order to log into a different desktop environment.

*I used xdm because it is lightweight but any other desktop manager such as lightdm, gdm or sddm will work too.

**When I tried this with Google Chrome, I ran into a problem. The window was not covering the entire screen and there was black space around it. If someone figures out how to fix this, please do comment it.